# bash - grep results writing to the terminal window rather than the defined .txt file

Tags: bash

I'm having trouble with the following code where the variable to be used by grep can be a single string or one that can contain spaces. The first section displays the results in the terminal window (as expected), and the second section prints the same results into results.txt if desired.

The problem is where I want to output to a results.txt file.. Where the lines of code include grep -ci & grep -ni, this particular output isn't going to results.txt. This is just displayed in the terminal window.. Everything else including where grep -cw / grep -nw is used is correctly being output to results.txt.

The string I am using which is being assigned to $searchstring is DUMMY ENTRY. As expected, the one entry of DUMMY ENTRY in the file is found for -cw & -nw and the 2 entries for DUMMY CODE & DUMMY TABLE are found with -ci & -ni

```
#USER INPUT#
echo "INPUT THE STRING TO SEARCH FOR" && echo && read searchstring
#Create searchstringa so a search for an exact match can be made#
searchstringa="${searchstring// /\[\[:space:\]\]}"

echo -e "\e[1;36mCount of exact matches:\e[0m"     
echo     sudo -u abc_mgr sh -c 'cd /users/search/; strings datafile1.DAT | grep -cw '${searchstringa}''
echo     echo -e "\e[1;36mCount of vague matches:\e[0m"
echo     sudo -u abc_mgr sh -c 'cd /users/search/; strings datafile1.DAT | grep -ci '${searchstring}''
echo     echo "**************************************"
echo      echo -e "\e[1;36mCase sensitive matches:\e[0m"
echo     sudo -u abc_mgr sh -c 'cd /users/search/; strings datafile1.DAT | grep -nw '${searchstringa}''
echo     echo "**************************************"
echo     echo -e "\e[1;36mCase insensitive matches:\e[0m"
echo     sudo -u abc_mgr sh -c 'cd /users/search/; strings datafile1.DAT | grep -ni '${searchstring}''
echo     echo "Input PRINT to print results to results.txt or Ctrl +C to quit" && echo && read printoutput

printfile=/users/search/results.txt

echo     if [[ $printoutput = PRINT ]] then
sudo -u abc_mgr sh -c 'cd /users/search/; echo -e "Count of exact matches:\n" >> '$printfile'
sudo -u abc_mgr sh -c 'cd /users/search/; strings datafile1.DAT | grep -cw '"${searchstringa}"'\n"' >> '$printfile'
sudo -u abc_mgr sh -c 'cd /users/search/; echo -e "Count of vague matches:\n" >> '$printfile'
sudo -u abc_mgr sh -c 'cd /users/search/; strings datafile1.DAT | grep -ci '${searchstring}'\n"' >> '$printfile
sudo -u abc_mgr sh -c 'cd /users/search/; echo -e "******************************\n\n" >> '$printfile'
sudo -u abc_mgr sh -c 'cd /users/search/; echo -e "Exact matches:\n" >> '$printfile'
sudo -u abc_mgr sh -c 'cd /users/search/; strings datafile1.DAT | grep -nw '"${searchstringa}"'\n"' >> '$printfile'
sudo -u abc_mgr sh -c 'cd /users/search/; echo -e "Count of vague matches:\n" >> '$printfile'    
sudo -u abc_mgr sh -c 'cd /users/search/; strings datafile1.DAT | grep -ni '${searchstring}'\n"' >> '$printfile
echo
echo "**************************************"
else :
fi
```

Comment: What's with all the `echo` statements? You're not executing any of the commands. And `echo if ...` doesn't work at all.

Comment: Can you distill that down to one repeatable, minimal example?

Comment: Please read the section titled [How to turn a bad script into a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info). Also https://shellcheck.net is the first place to figure out syntax problems. Be sure to include `#!/bin/bash` (or other) as your first line of scripting. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could take the string as a parameter (instead of asking for it interactively) and just pipe the script to 'tee' so that you get both, the output to the screen and also the same output to a file simultaneously.

Like:   cmd 2>&1 |tee outputfile.txt

where cmd could be something very close to the script you have already except that it reads an input as an argument.

And to not make the user worry about typing 'tee...' , you could wrap all this in a final script like:

wrapper_script.sh USER_KEYWORD

For example:

```
==wrapper_script.sh==
search_script.sh $@ 2>&1 |tee /path/results.txt
```

then the inner script is:

```
==search_script.sh==
# make sure there is at least one argument passed (keyword(s))
[[ ${#@} -ge 1 ]] || { echo "ERROR: provide at least one keyword argument"; exit 1 ; }
searchstringa="${@// /\[\[:space:\]\]}"
.
. <just the first block of your script>
. <don't ask the user if they want to save to a file.. it is already saved>
.
```

Comment: @Barmar I had to reformat what I had typed to include 4 spaces at the beginning of each line. I was rushing and missed a few.. Where there is a second echo this should be on the row underneath to inset a blank row.... Same with echo if. The if should be on the next row..

Comment: @erik258, sorry don't know what you mean